# Collect data using form and SharePoint list

Tags: outlook, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, data-entry, online-forms

I need to automate the process of collecting information from multiple clients via email and having them stored in a SharePoint list. I was thinking of using SharePoint forms and having it embedded in emails targeting a specific group of clients. And once the data has been filled in, they will be stored in a SharePoint list.

I am looking for customizable methods that doesn't involve much coding or atleast not the complicated type.

Appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

interesting case, but not too much details. 
In general what I would do is:

Create a list, create infopath form or custom webpart or even ootb form - to add item.

Send the link via email to the users with the link to add item form (see above). The user will open form, fill the data submit, done.

@user3345643 - provide more detail to discuss solution in details.